# Any tips on how to fix my code?

Tags: java, arrays

Here is the problem: When given an array `arr`, return an array which contains only odd integers in the original order from `arr`.

A Few Examples:

- youMakeMeOdd({1,2,3}) → {1, 3}
- youMakeMeOdd({1,3,5}) → {1, 3, 5}
- youMakeMeOdd({2,4,6}) → {}

And here is my code:

```
public int [] youMakeMeOdd(int [] arr)
{
    int x=0;
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]%2==1)
        {
            x++;
        }
    }

     for (int i=0, m=0, j=0; j<x; m++, j++)
     {
        if (arr[i]%2==1)
        {
            arr[m]=arr[j];
        }
     }   
 return arr;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: can u use arraylist?

Comment: Use an ArrayList, `List<int> list = new ArrayList<int>(Arrays.asList(array));` `alist.remove(1); //removes the element at position` 1

Comment: Actually I'm not quite sure if ArrayLists are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in Java are fixed-size: their length cannot be changed.

So you need to create and return a new array because the result might contain fewer elements.

Determine the size of the output array (count the odd values) to know the length of the result array, then iterate over your input and add the odd numbers to the output.

Example:

```
public static int[] youMakeMeOdd(int[] arr) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int n : arr)
        if (n % 2 == 1)
            count++;

    int[] result = new int[count];

    int i = 0;
    for (int n : arr)
        if (n % 2 == 1)
            result[i++] = n;

    return result;
}
```